# How to push innerHTML of the clicked button into an array using addEvenListener("click", ()=>function(array))

Tags: javascript, arrays, event-listener

I am trying to populate an array with the clicked buttons innerHTML. I have added an event listener and passed an array as the function parameter. The array is getting populated but with the value 'undefined'. I have tried passing this as a parameter but it does not work. Thank in advance!

```
var buttons1 = document.getElementById("1");
var array1 = [0];
buttons1.addEventListener("click", display);
buttons1.addEventListener("click", ()=>update(array1));

//On clicking the button, the array must be populated with the buttons innerHTML text.

function update(array){
array.push(this.innerHTML)
}
```

Comment: Line #4 seems to be missing a closing `)`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, thanksI have fixed that but its still not able to access the button.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: what is `this` in the `update` function? It is not the button. You can retrieve the button by using the parameter to `update`.

```
// e.srcElement is the button
buttons1.addEventListener("click", (e) => update(e, array1));

function update(e, array){
    array.push(e.srcElement.innerHTML)
}
```

Another option is to use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
// Bind buttons1 to this and array1 to the parameter
buttons1.addEventListener("click", update.bind(buttons1, array1));

function update(array){
    array.push(this.innerHTML);
}
```